# Rails JSON decode and to_json don't want work together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

```
> ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(13.to_json)
MultiJson::DecodeError: 743: unexpected token at '13'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.5.4/lib/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.5.4/lib/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/multi_json-1.0.4/lib/multi_json/engines/json_common.rb:9:in `decode'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/multi_json-1.0.4/lib/multi_json.rb:76:in `decode'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/json/decoding.rb:12:in `decode'
```

So just why?

Comment: It's likely that there is a problem with your code. Please add the code the cause the issue.

Comment: The whole code is only one command (ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(13.to_json)) started from rails console.

Comment: Oh my... I've read your code with the right attention sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, because `JSON.decode` expects more complicated structures than a single integer. Try wrapping it:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode({:my_integer => 13}.to_json)
```

In my opinon, I would call this a bug in rails.